# How to delete multiple rows in Gnumeric

Tags: spreadsheet, gnumeric

When I select one row in Gnumeric I get the option to `Delete 1 Row`:

[image: Delete one row]

When I select more than one in Gnumeric, I get a grayed out (non-functional) option to `Delete 3 Rows`:

[image: Delete three rows]

Clearly Gnumeric knows what I want to do but it just won't let me do it.

**How can I delete multiple rows in Gnumeric?**

I am using Gnumeric from the Debian 8 Jessie (stable) repositories.

Answer (score 2):

After posting to the mailing list, I received a response that deleting multiple rows is only possible when they are consecutive: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnumeric-list/2015-December/msg00001.html

I have opened an enhancement request to add the ability to delete multiple, non-consecutive rows: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=758997

I'm hoping the Gnumeric developers implement this feature in the future.